# Amazon API In Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests

What is the best way to use the amazon Product Advertising API in Python?

Seen previous answers, but all outdated and closed.

Most modules for the API call urllib which has errors with Python3 and SSL’s.

If anyone could give me the best way to work with it, it would greatly help.

Thanks

Comment: What Amazon API? Do you mean AWS? The official, supported Python SDK for AWS is boto3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the api yourself, then I find the [requests module](https://github.com/requests/requests) fantastic! Otherwise there is an [AWS SDK for Python](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

The [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) library is excellent and actively maintained. It doesn't have much support for MWS, but does support AWS very well.

Comment: boto3 is definitely the only recommendable way to go if you're using Python. The old boto project is slower to get in sync with new AWS features, has more bugs and a less consistent API.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately the OP wants the PAAPI, which boto3 does not support.

Comment: @spg The older boto project won't *ever* get in sync with new AWS services and features. It's only ever going to get fixes for critical issues. Everyone should use boto3, or plan to move to it.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS has their own python CLI package.

https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

pip install awscli

Comment: Think I may have been a bit brief in my question and not mentioned that I needed the product advertising API. I’m assuming this is an AWS api and not the product API, right?

Comment: Correct.  I provided a link for the AWS interface, not the Amazon Advertising API.  Actually, there are plenty of python libraries out there to handle the interface.  You should probably try one of those (like https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api) and then if/when you run into an SSL problem, you can ask a more specific question? : -)

Comment: I did just that, but people said that urllib is rather outdated and not very compatible with 3+. Ideally I need a way to change the simple product api library to use requests instead, but this is also proving to be a challenge as they are so based around urllib

Comment: I believe Requests uses urllib3 - https://github.com/shazow/urllib3.  Maybe it would be better to replace it with that instead of Requests?